# BizTalk 2010 encoding flat file UTF-8

Tags: encoding, biztalk

I am exporting a csv file using BizTalk and in my Flat file assembler I set the Target charset to UTF-8, but when I open the generated file using Notepad++ it tells me that used encoding in the file is ANSI.

Is there another thing to change?

EDIT:

I changed the property Preserve BOM to true and now it is working

Comment: Does the file contain any "special" characters at all? Or is it just plain English alphabet?

Comment: Yes, it contains special characters

Comment: And are those correctly displayed or not? Can you inspect the file with a hex editor and give some sample byte sequences for special characters? Also, it'd be interesting whether the beginning of the file contains a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or not.

Comment: I changed the property Preserve BOM to true and now it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the property Preserve BOM to true and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

It matters what have set in your schema and context. You need to set the encoding in you flatfile schema first.

Check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267840%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) at MSDN:

> You can specify the character encoding at several levels:
>
> - Schema. Set the codepage property in the flat file schema for the    document.
> - Component. Set the Target Charset component property in
> - Pipeline Designer. Message. Set the XMLNorm.TargetCharset property on    the message context.